# Very big form design

Tags: forms

I have very big form, it could have maximum ~1000 elements. It has many embedded forms which has another embedded forms, obviously they are collapsed by default.

My form has some entry points from which user can start, most of controls are not required, form is splitted into parts. Each subform can be folded to summary box.

I think that workflow with that type of form is ok. User can open it and in one page he can make many types of changes in data and in most cases those actions aren't connected each other.

Are there any design references, researches about such big one page forms design? Maybe some standards about designing UI with input controls pattern?

Comment: sounds like the kind of form that only a government department could love.

Comment: You are trying to achieve Formception.  Stated in UI Design Code of Conduct (UDCOC) article 27b, issue IV, section 321.4. And I quote, "Formception is not permitted in any way given, stated or practiced."

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide a workflow. A form that big on a single page will confuse people and lead to people not even bothering to fill it in.

Break it into smaller forms, and provide a wizard-style navigation process to move from one page to the next as the user fills in parts of the form.

Even then, 1000 data points is a lot for a single form, and a lot to ask people to fill in during a single session. So you would be well advised to allow people to leave the form partially filled in, and return to complete it later, without having to re-do what they've already entered. Some sort of session save facility is required.

Comment: SDC thanks for your answer I've updated my question with more concise (I hope) form description.